# acm.disjonctif() function not working in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column called 'geology (contains no missing data) which i want to transorm into indicator variables using the `acm.disjonctif()` function from the 'ade4' package in R. I'm using the following code:

```
library(ade4)
indic_geology = acm.disjonctif(data_genus$geology)
```

I have an error that says : **Error in 1:ncol(df) : argument of length 0**

I have tried transforming it into a factor :

```
data_genus$geology = as.factor(data_genus$geology)
indic_geology = acm.disjonctif(data_genus$geology)
```

But i still have the same error.

Here is what the column looks like :

```
data_genus$geology
   [1] 3 6 6 5 6 3 3 3 2 3 5 6 3 5 1 6 6 1 3 6 3 1 5 6 1 5 6 5 5 6 5 1 1 1 5 5 6 1 1 5 3 3 5
  [44] 6 3 5 6 3 3 5 1 3 3 6 5 3 6 6 3 6 6 3 6 6 6 6 6 6 3 3 3 6 2 3 3 1 6 2 1 6 5 3 2 3 1 6
  [87] 1 2 6 6 3 2 3 6 5 5 5 6 5 3 6 6 3 3 6 5 5 6 5 6 2 3 3 5 3 3 5 6 6 6 5 5 1 2 5 6 3 6 6
 [130] 1 5 3 6 3 3 5 3 5 1 3 5 2 5 5 5 6 3 3 5 5 3 5 3 6 6 3 3 5 3 2 6 5 3 3 3 3 6 3 6 5 6 5
 [173] 6 3 6 6 6 6 3 3 3 6 6 6 3 3 5 3 6 6 5 6 3 1 6 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 3 3 6 5 6 5 6 5 3 5 6 6 5
 [216] 6 3 3 5 6 6 6 3 6 3 1 2 1 3 3 6 6 3 1 3 3 6 6 1 6 5 1 1 6 6 2 3 6 6 3 3 1 6 5 1 3 6 6
 [259] 3 3 6 6 3 1 6 6 5 3 2 6 5 5 2 6 6 2 6 3 6 3 3 2 5 6 6 3 6 3 3 3 1 5 6 6 6 3 5 5 5 1 2
 [302] 5 6 6 6 3 3 3 6 6 3 3 6 1 5 6 6 5 3 3 1 6 6 6 5 2 3 3 5 3 6 6 2 3 6 1 3 3 3 6 6 3 3 3
 [345] 2 3 5 3 5 1 6 5 5 6 6 6 5 3 2 6 3 5 1 6 3 1 1 6 5 1 1 6 6 2 6 2 2 6 3 6 6 1 3 3 3 2 5
 [388] 3 3 6 6 2 6 6 6 1 6 6 3 3 3 3 2 6 3 6 6 1 5 6 6 6 3 1 5 2 3 3 5 3 6 6 5 6 6 6 6 5 1 1
 [431] 1 6 6 6 5 5 3 3 6 5 3 5 3 5 2 5 5 6 5 1 5 3 1 5 3 3 6 3 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 3 6 3 6 3 6 6
 [474] 6 5 3 3 5 6 6 2 3 6 6 5 6 5 5 5 5 6 3 2 5 1 3 5 5 3 6 5 1 5 6 6 3 6 3 3 3 1 5 3 3 2 5
 [517] 6 3 6 3 3 3 6 3 6 6 6 5 6 6 1 6 3 6 1 3 3 1 6 5 2 6 3 6 6 3 1 6 3 2 5 5 6 6 2 3 3 5 6
 [560] 2 6 6 6 6 6 2 6 5 5 1 6 3 6 1 3 6 1 2 5 6 5 2 5 1 5 6 6 5 5 6 5 1 6 1 6 6 1 3 6 3 2 5
 [603] 6 5 5 6 3 3 3 6 3 1 2 5 5 3 6 3 2 6 3 3 6 5 6 1 6 3 3 6 2 6 3 6 6 3 3 3 3 1 3 6 3 5 3
 [646] 3 1 3 3 1 2 1 6 5 3 3 6 3 6 3 3 5 6 5 2 5 6 5 2 3 5 5 6 6 3 5 6 1 3 6 6 5 5 3 2 5 6 5
 [689] 5 1 5 1 2 6 3 2 3 6 5 5 6 6 6 5 6 3 3 5 5 6 1 5 5 1 6 5 6 1 3 6 6 5 5 6 2 1 3 6 5 5 5
 [732] 5 5 5 1 6 1 6 3 5 2 1 3 3 5 3 3 6 6 2 1 6 3 6 1 5 6 1 3 6 6 6 6 3 1 6 1 6 6 3 1 6 5 3
 [775] 6 1 6 5 6 3 6 6 3 5 5 6 6 3 3 5 3 1 3 5 3 5 6 6 6 3 6 5 1 3 1 5 3 2 2 3 6 1 6 3 6 5 3
 [818] 1 3 2 1 3 6 6 3 6 3 5 6 3 6 5 6 3 3 6 3 3 3 6 5 5 6 6 3 3 3 3 6 3 6 3 6 6 6 6 1 6 6 6
 [861] 6 3 5 2 3 5 3 3 3 6 5 2 1 6 6 3 6 3 6 6 6 3 5 6 6 6 3 3 3 5 5 2 6 6 3 5 3 3 6 6 3 1 5
 [904] 5 3 3 5 2 3 3 3 1 6 3 1 3 3 6 6 6 1 3 6 3 6 3 6 3 3 6 6 3 5 5 6 3 3 3 5 3 6 3 3 3 1 5
 [947] 6 6 1 6 5 5 5 3 5 3 6 2 3 6 3 3 2 3 1 5 1 6 3 1 6 1 3 6 5 6 6 5 1 5 3 6 5 6 6 6 6 6 1
 [990] 5 6 6 3 5 5 3 3 6 5 5 1
Levels: 1 2 3 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I'm reading in the documentation of the function,which you can read just by running `?dudi.acm`, the function argument must be a `data.frame` of factors. You could try.

```
indic_geology = acm.disjonctif(data_genus[,"geology"])
```